# jquery-ui slider change value measurement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

In my application I'm using `jquery-ui` slider. Users able to change value of slider from 1 (month) to 60 (month). Actually 1-60 are months. According to the new requirements after 11, value of slider should be changed to 1 (year), 2 (year) and so on. My concern is the following, can I have this kind of slider, which changes values measurement ? If yes, pls give me example.

Here is my source.

```
$(".slider").slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 60,
        step: 1
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst this is not possible out of the box,

I have made a working fiddle for you here http://jsfiddle.net/JFJKP/

HTML:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<br/>
<div class='showAltValue'>Click to Show Alt Value</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 60,
    altValue: 'Nothing Selected',
    step: 1,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        value = ui.value;
        years = Math.floor(value / 12);
        months = value % 12 // value modulus of 12 gives remainder

        if (years > 1) {
            yearString = 'years';
        } else {
            yearString = 'year';
        }

        if (months > 1 && months != 0) {
            monthString = 'months';
        } else {
            monthString = 'month';
        }
        // Now format the output.
        if (years == 0) {
            altValue = months + ' ' + monthString;
        } else {
            if (months == 0) {
                //dont' show months
                altValue = years + ' ' + yearString;
            } else {
                altValue = years + ' ' + yearString + ' ' + months + ' ' + monthString;
            }
        }
        // Now alert the altValue
        alert(altValue);
        // You can now use this as a label Value somewhere and even store it as a slider attribute as such
        $(event.target).slider("option", "altValue", altValue);
    }
});

$('.showAltValue').click(function () {
    alert($('.slider').slider("option", "altValue"));
});
```

This should at least get you on the right track.

Comment: Glad to have helped ;)